# Increase the thickness of a line and color it

Tags: color, tkz-euclide

I have been working on a small figure in which I want to increase the thickness of half of the line (the right half) and want to change color.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
%\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 12/0/B, 6/0/C}

\draw[thick](A)--(B);
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,size=0.15cm](A,B,C)

\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$(-)$}](0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$a=2$}](0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$(+)$}](12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$b=3$}](12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$(-)$}](6,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$f(x_{1})=f(2.5)$}](6,0){C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple. I'm surprised nobody has answered yet.

You already have a `\draw` and the 3 points you need.

Just divide the original `\draw` in two and add the color and line width you like to the right half.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1 in,bottom=1 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,xcolor,graphicx}
%\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 12/0/B, 6/0/C}

\draw[thick](A)--(C);
\draw[red, line width=4pt](C)--(B);
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,size=0.15cm](A,B,C)

\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$(-)$}](0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$a=2$}](0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$(+)$}](12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$b=3$}](12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint[label=below:{$(-)$}](6,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint[label=above:{$f(x_{1})=f(2.5)$}](6,0){C}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention